# How can I know if a ListView overflows the screen when initially rendered?

Tags: flutter

I am creating an image scrollbar class implemented with a horizontal ListView.  The ScrollBar should display a left or right arrow depending on whether the ListView has overflowed the screen in either direction.  When the user scrolls, the arrows can be updated with a NotificationListener (see code below).  However, I do not know how to set the initial state of the ScrollBar before the user has triggered a Notification.

I also tried using a ScrollController to access the initial position of the ListView, but it seems that this information is not available until after the build method returns.  (Error message reads, "ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.")

```dart
class ImageScrollbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageScrollbarState createState() => _ImageScrollbarState();
}

class _ImageScrollbarState extends State<ImageScrollbar> {

  bool _moreToLeft = false;
  bool _moreToRight = false; // <-- how to properly initialize?
  // how can we know within the build method whether the listview
  // has gone off screen, in which case _moreToRight = true?

  // update arrows in response to user action (scrolling)
  _updateArrows(ScrollMetrics sm) {
    setState(() {
      _moreToLeft = sm.pixels != sm.minScrollExtent;
      _moreToRight = sm.pixels != sm.maxScrollExtent;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // create image widgets
    var image_widgets = [Image.asset('example.png', fit: BoxFit.cover)];

    // build the scroll bar
    var _scrollController = new ScrollController();
    var sa = ListView(
               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
               scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
               controller: _scrollController,
               children: image_widgets);

    // print(_scrollController.position); <-- causes error because _scrollController not yet attached

    var sb = <Widget>[
               NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                 onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
                   if (scrollNotification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
                     _updateArrows(scrollNotification.metrics);
                   }
                 },
                 child: sa,
              )];

    if (_moreToLeft) {
      sb += Positioned(
          left: -30,
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_left, size: 72),
        );
    }

    if (_moreToRight) {
      sb += Positioned(
          right: -30,
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right, size: 72),
        );
    }

    return Stack(
             alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
             overflow: Overflow.visible,
             children: sb,
           );
  }
}
```

Once the user scrolls, the `_updateArrows` method is called and all is good.  However, when the app first loads, there is no right arrow even if the ListView is in fact overflowing the screen to the right.  This is because I set the default value of `_moreToRight` to `false`, but I need to determine it dynamically based on the actual layout without knowing in advance how many images there will be in the ScrollBar.  (I just used one image in my example code to keep it simple.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workable solution.

1) Change from NotificationListener to a ScrollListener.  This isn't really necessary (I don't think), but the code was simpler.

2) Call the state-setting function in a post-frame callback.

3) Sleep for a short period to make sure that the ListView has been fully rendered.

Basically:

```dart
bool _moreToLeft = false;
bool _moreToRight = false;

ScrollController _controller;

_scrollListener() {
  setState(() {
    _moreToLeft = _controller.position.pixels != _controller.position.minScrollExtent;
    _moreToRight = _controller.position.pixels != _controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
  });
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = ScrollController();
  _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
    // must introduce this lag to make sure the scrollbar is completely rendered
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds : 1000));
    _scrollListener();
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

// ...

ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  controller: _controller,
  children: kids);

// ...

}
```

Comment: And remember to import "dart:async";